# How can I fix this indexing error in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, perceptron

I am trying to create a perceptron function in MATLAB. I believe there is some sort of an indexing error in this double nested loop, possibly the delta_theta, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Can someone assist me? Thank you.

```
 for jj=1:niter
    for ii=1:N 
      if Y(ii,jj)~=t(ii,jj)
    delta_theta = bias*(Y(ii,jj)-t(ii,jj))*X(ii,:)
    theta = theta + delta_theta
     end
    end
end
```

Thank you so much for taking a look at it. I appreciate it :)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow astromonomical! i do curious, what is the exact error message say?

Comment: Thank you Bagus! This code is in a function, so when I use the command window to run the function, I get the following error:

Comment: Not enough input arguments.

Error in perceptron_neuron (line 37)
        delta_theta = bias*(Y(ii,jj)-t(ii,jj))*X(ii,:)

Comment: Another error I am getting is Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

Error in perceptron_neuron (line 36)
     if Y(ii,jj)~=t(ii,jj)

Comment: can you post your function input arguments and how did you call it? regarding "exceeds array bounds" is pretty clear that you are trying to access something outside the matrix. we can't quite figure this out without the input.

Comment: a [mcve] would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to contain a [mre], also copy-paste the full error message into your post.